# Is it possible to have a directory listed and hide specific files based on an excluder, i.e HTTP_Host?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is it possible to have a directory listed and hide specific files based on an excluder, i.e HTTP_Host?

```
Request for cloud -> from example.com -> Hide all files beginning with xamplee_
Request for cloud -> from xamplee.com -> Hide all files beginning with example_
```

I tried the following with no success:

```
IndexIgnore xxx

Options -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^xamplee_ xxx [NC,L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xamplee\.com$ [NC]
IndexIgnore êxample_ xxx [NC,L]
```

I'm not even sure if it is possible at all. A different approach would also be welcome.

Comment: This is not possible with only entries in `.htaccess` style files. You need an index document for this, typically written in some scripting language on the server. Inside that script you can create whatever index entries you like.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. This is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid that? Gives you much more flexibility. If you don't like scripting, then you could also change the index generation module of the apache http server. That would be c or c++  code. Sounds like much more hassle to me, but typically it will be a lot faster...

Comment: Oh ok, you mean something different than a php script? I've never heard before of that. Can you provide a link with some more info? Thanks

Comment: For scripting _one of_ the many possibilities would be the php language. Simply because it is extremely well suited for the task and also wide spread. But there is no reasons why you cannot use any other scripting language available on your system. About reimplementing apaches index module: sure that is possible, as all open source products the code behind it is no secret. You can study and modify it for your purpose, no restriction here. But as said: it will be a lot of hassle, requires knowledge of those languages and the http servers architecture and a full build chain.

Comment: Sure, I meant the scripting thing, the easier way of course. Can you point me in that direction somehow?

Comment: What do you mean with that? php is just a typical example for such a case due to reaons mentioned above. You appear to know about php scripting. All scripting solutions follow the same pattern. So this would be more a question of what scripting language you have available on your system, are willing to make available or simply prefer to use. So what is your question then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, based on the exchange in the comments to the question here some means to get you started (hopefully):

The apache http server comes with a bundle of modules. One of those is `mod_dir` which provides features to generate directory listings.

It offers a standard listing but also allows more flexible usage. The "DirectoryIndex" directive allows to declare any object as usable index document for a directory. With this you can configure any type of handler generating such an issue. Typical examples would be static html documents or a dynamic `index.php` document, so a php script generating an html based index of the directory at hand. Of course any other scripting language can be chosen just as well. 
Its documentation helps with the details: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html

The the approach here would be to pick a suitable scripting language which is available inside your environment (or make it available) and point the DirectoryIndex directive to a script coded in that language.

Another approach would be to create a rewriting rule to relay all requests to directories to a script. Comes out more or less the same as long as the script knows what directory it should create the index for.

That way whenever a request to a directory is coming in that script well be executed and expected to provide the correct html index document for this directory. Inside such a script you are free to do and output whatever you like.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, arkascha. I see now what you mean. Unfortunately my rep is too low to upvote you but I'll give you a green checkmark because you answered my question.

Comment: All fine, glad I could be of help. Your reputation here will increase, you will see. Take this site as a give and take contract. It is your turn now :-)